# Display a message once (like a cookie consent) on first visit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website and am trying to display a message at the top of the page (inside the header) so it only appears once on every visit/session. An example of this the 'Book an appointment' green bar at the top of this website:
https://www.tiffany.co.uk

My website is here: https://vitrify.tempurl.host/

I've got as far as having a message appear (orange panel at top of page) but currently it appears every time a page is loaded. I just want it to appear once, just like a cookie consent.

I've spent hours looking for a solution but, as I'm not a programmer, I'm struggling. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the HTML:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("topDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.topDIV {
  color: #000000;
    font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.topDIV a:link, .topDIV a:visited {
  color: #000000!important;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
    line-height: 1.2        ;
}

span.topDIV {

}

.topDIV a:hover {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.50) !important;
    display: inline-block;
}

.button-x {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: -5px;
    background:none; 
    border:none; 
    color:rgb(0,0,0) ;
    cursor: pointer; 
    vertical-align: 0px;
}
.button-x:before {
    font-family: 'Times';
    content: "X";
        font-size:30px;
        vertical-align:0px;
    opacity:0.5;
}
.button-x:hover {
    opacity:1!important;
}
```

```html
<span class = "topDIV">Welcome to <em>Vitrify</em>. Following in the finest traditions of vitreous enamelled jewellery. <a href = "#">Find&nbsp;out&nbsp;more.</a></span><button class = "button-x" onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use sessionStorage or localStorage. Only by CSS it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just don't know enough about coding to go any further. The CSS is fine for styling, just the Javascript at the top that needs some input.

Comment: try learning. This is best all i can do.

Comment: try setting a cookie on first visit (but that requires some server side stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above you need to use *localStorage* to solve your problem.

- Need to know when page is loaded
- Get value from the *localStorage*
- Add event to the button (i removed the onclick event from the html for a cleaner solution)
- After click set value for *localStorage* and hide item
- If *localStorage* have value, hide the element

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Jnetc/qgdaywr7/2/)

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const topDiv = document.querySelector('.topDIV');
  const buttonX = document.querySelector('.button-x');

  // Get value from localStorage when open the page
  const lS = localStorage.getItem('first-visit');

  // Add button 'click' event
  buttonX.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Set value to the localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('first-visit', false);
    // hide DOM element
    topDiv.style.display = 'none';
  });

  // This does not check on the first visit to the page
  // If localStorage have value, hide DOM element
  if (lS) topDiv.style.display = 'none';
});
```

**Html**

```
<span class="topDIV"
  >Welcome to <em>Vitrify</em>.Following in the finest traditions of
  vitreous enamelled jewellery.
  <a href="#">Find out more.</a>
</span>
<button class="button-x"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you ЖнецЪ, with your help I managed to do it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag "showTopMessage:true" in your local storage or session storage based on one time msg to user or every time he visits. respectively.

On Cross/close icon click set the flag "showTopMessage:false".

```html
       const showTopBar = "SHOW_TOP_BAR"; 
       const[showTopBar,setShowTopBar] = useState(true);

      useEffect(()=>{
        const saveState = localstorage.getItems(showTopBar);

        if(saveState) setShowTopBar(saveState);
        else localstorage.setItem(showTopBar, true);
      },[]);

      const handleTopBarClose = () => {
        setShowTopBar(false);
        localstorage.setItem(showTopBar, false);
      }
 

      return(
      <div>
      {
        showTopBar && <TopBarComponent onClose={handleTopBarClose}/>
      }
      </div>
      )
```

Comment: Yep ur right, but It would be nicer if you included some code to make your point ( like jsfiddle ).

Comment: Please can you explain how I do this?